# Последовательность и время выполнения команд в цикле range

Tags: python

**Есть код:**

```
for _ in range(10):
       time.sleep(1)
       subprocess.run('arp -d', check=True)

       time.sleep(30)
       with open('File.txt', 'wb', 0) as file:
            subprocess.run('arp -a', stdout=file, check=True)
```

Мне нужно чтобы первая команда arp-d выполнялась, а через 30 секунд выполнялась следующая команда arp-a, потом снова выполнилась arp-d и так далее 10 раз

Не могу выяснить правильно ли выполнил последовательность? Важно чтобы команда выполнялась через 30 секунд после первой команды,

Comment: Выглядит нормально. А в связи с чем возник вопрос, что-то не так работает как вы задумали?

Comment: Хотел точно удостовериться что последовательность и тайминги правильные, очень важно для программы,

Comment: Так вы добавьте отладочную печать в виде чего-то такого в соответствующие места кода `print('запускаю arp -a')` и с секундомером посмотрите - правильно ли работает, если хотите убедиться. Ну или можно в лог файл писать инфу и потом по времени в логе смотреть. Всегда полезно проконтролировать свой код с помощью отладочной печати или лога.

Comment: почему у вас вопрос об одном, а заголовок совсем о другом?

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать, а на счет заголовка - что не так? в коде range функция присутствует

Comment: @Ерасыл Но суть вопроса не в `range` же. Хотя в данном случае действительно сложно придумать хороший заголовок

Comment: в коде еще много чего присутсвует, почему бы все это сразу не вписать в заголовок? Ну чтоб наверняка. Вы в больницу всегда в стоматологу ходите, без разницы что болит? Ну а что, зубы же в организме присутствуют...

Comment: @Эникейщик Автор начинающий всё-таки, зачем уж вы так прям )

Comment: @CrazyElf вот как раз самое подходящее время обзавестить хорошими привычками. Пригодится и в жизни и в работе.